# Does get_query_var() works for custom page on front end?

Tags: wordpress

So far I tried this way, But no luck with this, Is that really possible or not?

```
add_action('init','add_my_error');
function add_my_error() { 
   global $wp; 
   $wp->add_query_var('list'); 
}
```

Comment: and how did you call get_query_var() ? and where ?

Comment: I called on that page using get_query_var()

Comment: in the title you speak about get_query_var() and you show us the code of add_query_var() ... so can you be more clear about where you put each portion of code

Comment: @JaedMosharraf What **file** are you putting this code into?

Comment: This way I tried to get the var instead of using $_GET

if ( get_query_var('list') )  $list= get_query_var('list');

Comment: On a shortcode I tried to get the var